# Getting ORA-00904 when creating a stored procedure that references a dbms package

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm creating a stored procedure to get data from a bucket in Object store and load it into a table. But I'm getting a error `ORA-00904` when creating the SP. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
create or replace procedure watcher_load
is
 v_exists varchar2(1) := 'F';

 CURSOR c_filelist is
        select replace(regexp_substr(OBJECT_NAME ,'[^_]*(_|$)',1,2), '_', '' ) 
                object_name,
                bytes 
        from DBMS_CLOUD.LIST_OBJECTS('user_cred','https://objectstorage.oraclecloud.com/n/bunge/bingo_subside/o/')
        where object_name like '20%_%_bingo_hourly_res.json';

begin

 FOR i in c_filelist
  LOOP

   select 'T' into v_exists from watcher_table where filename = i.object_name;
   if v_exists != 'T' then
        insert into watcher_table (region, filename, bytes)
        values (i.region, i.object_name, i.bytes);
   end if;

  END LOOP;

 commit;

end watcher_load;
/
```

Errors for PROCEDURE WATCHER_LOAD:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/9      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/15     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DBMS_CLOUD"."LIST_OBJECTS": invalid
         identifier

17/4     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
17/65    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "I"."FILENAME": invalid identifier
17/65    PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid
19/9     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
20/39    PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid
20/41    PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Comment: Do you have access to DBMS_CLOUD package? Can you please check with Oracle Admin? As per oracle -  Note:To run DBMS_CLOUD subprograms with a user other than ADMIN you need to grant EXECUTE privileges to that user. For example, run the following command as ADMIN to grant privileges to adwc_user: Link here- https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/dbms-cloud.html#GUID-3D0A5361-672C-467D-AA90-656B1B4D4E37

Comment: Yes the user has access to DBMS_CLOUD package. I can run queries that can return rows from this command, but the stored procedure errors out.

Comment: @koushiksinharoy actually that fixed it :). Very wierd and not sure how the user was able to run queries using dbms_cloud, but looks like for the stored procedure, the user needs explicit privileges to the package. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @belve - the user probably previously only had privileges granted via a role, which by default aren't honoured in stored PL/SQL. Look for answers here talking about AUTHID.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

As per oracle - Note:To run DBMS_CLOUD subprograms with a user other than ADMIN you need togrant EXECUTE privileges to that user. For example, run the following command as ADMIN to
  `grant privileges to adwc_user` 
  Link here- https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/dbms-cloud.html#GUID-3D0A5361-672C-467D-AA90-656B1B4D4E37